# What would be the response code for an error originated by a client mistake in direction of an other client?

Tags: http

I'm building a service where clients (A) can write code, and other clients (B) can consume that code by making HTTP requests on my service.

The code provided by client A can contain errors. I think `500` errors should only be served for errors originated from my service, not by my clients A code.

What would be an appropriate response error code for that type of errors?

Comment: 5xx if the server did something wrong, 4xx if the client did something wrong. It doesn't matter who wrote the code.

Comment: Thanks, 5xx it will be

Comment: I guess I'll go with the 502 code, since my service is kind of acting like a proxy between the client B request and the client A code